# Custom templateName in Ember 2.x component

Tags: ember.js

How can I set dynamically `templateName` in Ember 2.x components.

Because old properties from `Ember.View` is deprecaded.

Comment: you might have implemented wrong. You dont need to set template names dynamically..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `layoutName` to set dynamic templates.

For Eg: assume a computed property, say `dynamicTemplate` returns the required template to be rendered

`{{my-component layoutName=dynamicTemplate}}`